# How to put an element on the right of some rows in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, xml, alignment, rows, android-relativelayout

i created this layout for my list rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/press_event" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewNameM"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_button_pressed" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameUser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#f6911e"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewDetails1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewNameM"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/catUser"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/catUser"
            android:contentDescription="@string/arrowS"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#4a4c4d" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingUser"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/catUser"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="@integer/five"
            android:stepSize="0.1" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewDetails2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewDetails1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cityUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#4a4c4d" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I would like to keep the arrow on the right of the rows, but i would to set it in the middle, like this:

[image]

I make several tries, but i cannot reach my goal. How to do that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffffff" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewNameM"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cccccc" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameUser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#f6911e"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewDetails1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewNameM"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/chevron" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Hotel"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#4a4c4d" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingUser"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/catUser"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="0.1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cityUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/catUser"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Roma"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#4a4c4d" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_below="@id/ratingUser"
            android:textColor="#4a4c4d"
            android:text="22km"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is looks like you want.

Comment: Thank you, it worked... i just had to add `android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"` to arrow TextView. Thank you so much, i really appreciated your answer.

Comment: You shouldn't encourage bad code. LinearLayout is useless, and inner RelativeLayout is useless too.

Comment: I've just edited one from question. It's obvious that it's not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like you would in real life:

1. Place caret on the right.
2. Place rating on the left of the caret, below separating line.
3. Place distance to the left of the caret, below rating.
4. ...

Answer (score 0):

Create layout of this type using Layout weight in LinnerLayout

Comment: Do you mean creating another RelativeLayout that contains just the caret? Then use weight Layout where?

Comment: No use a Linnar-Layout for that..because weight is not applicable for relative layout.